# Trailing colons and dash's builtin test command

Tags: shell, test, dash

What's the meaning of a trailing colon to dash's builtin `test` (or `[`) command? I was surprised when I found that `if [ ... ]: ; then .. ; fi` works (at all) in `dash`, but not `bash`, and it seems to be because the builtin's behavior differs from the command's.

```
$ /usr/bin/\[ 1 ] && echo 1
1
$ /usr/bin/\[ 1 ]: && echo 1
/usr/bin/[: missing `]'
$ [ 1 ]: && echo 1
1
```

Comment: What does `[ 1 ]foo && echo 1` do?  My wild initial guess is that dash is checking whether the argument starts with `]` instead of whether it's equal to `]`.

Comment: Looks like `[ 1 ]foo && echo 1` prints `1`, so @Arcege's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be more of an issue if parsing the commands.  `bash` expects the closing bracket to be the last argument and complains if it not exactly a "]" string.

```
bash$ [ 1 ]
bash$ [ 1 ] hi
bash: [: missing `]'
bash$ [ 1 ]hi
bash: [: missing `]'
bash$ dash
$ [ 1 ]
$ [ 1 ] hi
dash: 2: [: missing ]
$ [ 1 hi]
dash: 3: [: missing ]
$ [ 1 ]:
$ [ 1 ]hi
$
```

The `dash` shell will just make sure that the first character is "]" and ignore the rest.  If the "]" is not in the first character of the last argument, then it returns a similar error as `bash`.